# Why don't I get an opt in url when releasing to alpha testing on Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I am very new to Google Play so please bear with me, but I am really struggling to get my test app to give me an opt in url.  My app is created using React Native and expo and I have build my APK file and uploaded it to Google Play.

I have set up all screenshots etc and filled out any other bits which needed ticking, however when I go to create an alpha closed test, I am constantly stucj at 'Pending publication'.

I set one off last night after hearing it can take up to 3 hours to show, however there is still no opt in link 12 hours later.

I have just tried again as per the screenshot below, with one tester in the closed tester section, it seems to have released fine but still no link?!

I have made sure I added and enabled the tester before I published as I have heard that may cause the link to not show as well.

Other posts suggest there is a publish button, but I cannot see this anywhere other than 'Release to production' which i'm too scared to hit!

Any help would be very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Its showing seconds ago in Roll-out history. So you should wait for few hours until your app gets published. By the way, for testing, you can try Internal Test, it pretty much publishes the app instantly.

Comment: Actually this time, third time lucky it did actually publish it, no idea why my first two times didn’t work.